# PowerShell Get-Volume HealthStatus

Tags: powershell

Get-Volume returns an integer 0 which means healthy. Sometimes it returns the word "Healthy" I tried using `$k.HealthStatus.ToString()` and it randomly returns string or integer.

```
$hdsk = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -ScriptBlock { Get-Volume|where {$_.Size -gt 1GB}|Sort DriveLetter}

foreach($k in $hdsk)
{
```

Comment: That's interesting, but what's the question?   It probably has something to do with different versions of software installed on the target machines.

Comment: why would someone downvote an issue someone is having? that's disrespectful. i thought the issue was pretty clear, it should return a string but returns an integer. it has nothing to do with versions of software installed

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question for reasons someone might downvote a question.

Comment: This isn't a site for "issues", it's a site for questions and answers.   The question gets voted up or down in relationship to how useful an answer to it might be to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the extra parameters returned the string as expected.

```
$hdsk = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -ScriptBlock { Get-Volume } |where $_.Size -gt 1GB}|Sort DriveLetter
```